# How to I Create My own 3d modals in unity5?

Tags: unity, 3d, models

How to I Create My own 3D modals in unity 5?
Actually,I don't know how to create a 3d modals in unity 5.If anyone is know, PLZ tell me...!

Comment: 3DSMax, Maya, Blender, etc can be used to create 3D models, which can later be imported to Unity.

Comment: Welcome to game dev stack exchange! Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for this Question and Answer site; please see the [rules](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information. However, if you have any _specific_ question, by all means, please ask again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Unity3d has no built-in 3d modeling tool. However, it can import models made with other editors in a large variety of formats. You can use almost every common 3d modeling program to create 3d models and then import them into Unity.

For software recommendations regarding 3d modeling programs, please ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com